# Problems using node-sass with AWS Lambda Function

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, lambda, node-sass

I have created a Lambda function that compiles sass from a string template.

The program runs just fine when tested locally on an Amazon Machine Image with Node 4.3 (same as Lambda).

When I test the function in Lambda, the process times out after the allotted 10 seconds.   When I add a whole bunch of `console.log()` statements to see where the program is terminating, it doesn't get past `var sass = require('node-sass');`

My initial thought was the native libraries were compiled for the wrong OS, but the AWS documentation states I am using the correct environment.

Just to be sure, I reran `npm rebuild node-sass` after I double checked I had the right version of Node.

Still didn't seem to work.   Perhaps it could be something else?

```
console.log('COMPILER -- ln 3 1');  //gets here!
var Promise = require('bluebird');
const _ = require('lodash');
var sass = require('node-sass');
console.log('COMPILER -- ln 7');  // never gets here!
```

- **EDIT**: I tried azure functions and run into the same issue.   I used Kudu to run `npm rebuild node-sass` but that doesn't seem to help.